# no records found in stored procedure cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have written a simple cosmos stored procedure

```
function a()
{
    var context = getContext();
    var response = context.getResponse();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

    var filterQuery = 'SELECT  * FROM c';

    collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, { pageSize: -1 },
        function (err, documents) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!documents || !documents.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody('No Records found');
            }
            else {
                response.setBody(response.getBody());
            }
        });
}
```

However on execution, I always get "No records found", though on running the query separately, I do get records. Also I have give partition key value.

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you provide the incorrect partition key so that no data could be found.

SP code：

```
function a()
{
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

    var filterQuery = 'SELECT  * FROM c';

    collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, { pageSize: -1 },
        function (err, documents) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!documents || !documents.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody('No Records found');
            }else {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody(documents);
            }
        });
}
```

Sample data:

[image]

Provide partition key and execute:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay. I have also done same thing, but somehow I am not able to retrieve the data.

Comment: @DivyaPoojari Never mind, please provide some sample documents and i will try my best to simulate your solution.

Comment: @DivyaPoojari Hi,any progress now?

Comment: If I give the id and the partition key value same, then I get records. Also I have noticed, neither Upsert nor replace works if the id and the partition key is different. Any idea how and why I am facing this issue. As far as I can see the screenshots attached by you, they are different

Comment: @DivyaPoojari Sorry,not get your idea. What do you mean give the id and the partition key value sam? You could edit your original question and add the screeshots or your total stored procedure and some example documents. Let me try to simulate your situation as well as i can.